# A difficult to access DB from ASP.net code

Tags: asp.net, html, sql-server

I have the following code:

```
sql="SELECT  COUNT(*) AS CurrentInvoice from [Invoices].[dbo].[InvoiceSentInformation] WHERE (InvoiceSeries = 18) AND (InvoicePeriodStartDate='"&SelectedMonth&"') AND (CustomerBillingGroupId IN (2, 3, 11))" 
Response.Write SelectedMonth
'Response.Write sql
r.open sql,c_SQL,3,3
IF r.recordcount>0 THEN
    CurrentInvoice=r("CurrentInvoice")
    for i=1 to r.recordcount
   %>
       <TR align="center">
        <TD><%=CurrentInvoice%></TD>
        <TD>
         <%


  %>
```

And the output is: 0.

When I run the query in my sql-server, the result is a number > 15,000.
How can I fix my code to show the same output as I see in my database?

Comment: you sure you are running the query against the same db? The code looks fine. (Is this asp classic? It could be vb.net but it feels like asp classic). Check your query strings, if you organization is typical, there is probably a dev, staging, prod db all slightly different.

Comment: what is the value of SelectedMonth? if it is a date, then the format maybe the wrong culture (31/12/12 vs 12/31/12)

Answer (score 0):

in your for loop, you seem to loop from 1 to the r.recordcount.
this means that the for loop isn't entered and so nothing is displayed.

have you tried just displaying CurrentInvoice without the for loop?
That should then just display the count from the SQL

Comment: Record count should always be one since the only expression is an aggregate, so the loop should be done once, but I agree the for statement should be remvoed.

Comment: Hey thanks everyone for the help I should add:<TD><%Response.Write r("CurrentInvoice")%></TD>

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you should remove the for loop - when you have select aggregate() from table, the result will always be one row, even if the table is empty.

It may be that you just excluded it in the snippet, but for a table to be displayed, it needs proper formatting.  It looks like the above may leave an open  and never close the .  Should the second  have been a ?

I'd suggest viewing the source of the HTML output so you can see everything written my your code. I suspect the zero you are attributing to the above may come from somewhere else, and the above may not be outputting anything visible (without viewing source).

As for the SQL, FYI, you can see a performance improvement by using count(1) instead of count(*) - the latter still has SQL check the metadata for all columns.

Comment: Hey thanks everyone for the help
I should add:<TD><%Response.Write r("CurrentInvoice")%></TD>